# Issues in setting up Qt Creator with a project, error running 'git': execve: No such file or directory

Tags: git, ubuntu, qt-creator, execve

I'm trying to set up a new ubuntu machine (I just migrated from a mac) and have gotten to qt creator and taken a first stab at setting up my kit and environment.  When it tries to parse one of the *.qbs files though I get an error saying

```
Error:Error running '/git': execve: No such file or directory
```

git is all set up and as far as I know functioning properly.

Also to note this isn't my part of the code (I just do the fortran programming and maintenance in a core section) And the guy maintaining this is working some other high priority projects.

Comment: It's saying that git should exist in the root directory. It should be in /usr/bin. It'll be a config error somewhere or a var has not been set up properly.

Comment: Okay I did sent the git path to /usr/bin. I'll start digging on that more.  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out I had a typo in the environment variable setting the git path (face palm)  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Happens to us all.... happens to us all...